# WooCommerce +/- quantity buttons are missing

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using the last WooCommerce version and I have no +/- quantity buttons before and after the single product page quantity input field. In the corresponding template ("/global/quantity-input.php") there's only the input field, +/- input elements are missing.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WooCommerce has depreciated the quantity selector buttons in version 2.3 and above.

There is a separate plugin by WooCommerce to get back the quantity selectors
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-quantity-increment/

Reference: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-more-quantity-selector-after-update

Answer (score 2):

The current WooCommerce uses the html5 number input which does not have separate plus and minus buttons, though some themes might still be adding them with JavaScript.